# Strange Segmentation fault when dealing with files

Tags: c++, file-io, segmentation-fault, variable-declaration

I am trying to parse a file, and I am getting a strange segmentation fault. This is the code I am using:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    FILE *the_file;
    the_file = fopen("the_file.txt","r");

    if (the_file == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Error opening file.\n";
        return 1;
    }

    int position = 0;
    while (!feof(the_file))
    {
        unsigned char *byte1;
        unsigned char *byte2;
        unsigned char *byte3;
        int current_position = position;

        fread(byte1, 1, 1, the_file);
    }
}
```

I compile it with the command

```
g++ -Wall -o parse_file parse_file.cpp
```

If I remove the line in the while loop that declares current_position, the code runs without issue. I can also move that declaration above the declarations of the unsigned char pointers and the code will run without issue. Why does it seg fault with the declaration right there?

Answer (score 8):

`byte1` is an uninitialised pointer; you need to allocate some storage.

```
unsigned char *byte1 = malloc(sizeof(*byte1));

fread(&byte1, 1, 1, the_file);

...

free(byte1);
```

Or even better, don't use a pointer at all:

```
unsigned char byte1;

fread(&byte1, 1, 1, the_file);
```